lookups / maps for grafana dashboards and panels
I have a grafana dashboard that uses a static lookup from a variable to get a value out, to use as a query filter. As an example, for a variable called item, which uses a text property to look up color:
apple : red, banana : yellow, orange : orange, grape : purple, pea : green`

If someone selects banana from the variable selector, I can use ${item:text} to reference the color, and will get yellow in a panel query.
I now need to add a 2nd property to each item, for example category, which could have apple : fruit and pea : vegetable.  I have set up a 2nd variable which contains the same keys, but with different text values (e.g. apple : fruit, peas : vegetable, etc) - but I don't want have the 2nd variable exposed / listed for users to select, I just want to use it for a lookup as a hidden variable - is it possible to look up from ${category:text} but using the key currently set for $item? have not been able to create a lookup across multiple variables.
Alternatively, instead of using a separate variable, is there a way to use more complex values for variables? e.g. something like this:
apple : { color : red, category : fruit }, pea : { color : green, category : veg }

The values for the 2 properties are predictable, so i could even use a constructed string / tokens if the panel query supports it, e.g.
apple : red_fruit, pea : green_veg

and then is there a way to do something like split(${item : text}, "_")[0] for the color, and then use [1] for the category (or a regex function)?

No, using value of one value to select value of another is not possible in Custom variables. You'll need to use a query variable to get additional variables based on selected one. See how this can be accomplished in some data sources here.

Does this answer your question? Dashboard variable based on another variables

@markalex - that gives me an approach to solve this - if you want to post as an answer, i can mark it as accepted.

I don't have anything to add to linked answer. I'd prefer if you accepted proposed duplicate.

* And not deleted this question: useful signpost, makes finding answer easier, while DRY, etc.
